# lodsh filter not working on array of object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of object which looks like

```
const test = [{"Active": {"Id":'1', 'Name': 'Peter'}, 'Collect' : {'Id':'2', 'Name': 'John'}},{"Active": {"Id":'1', 'Name': 'Peter'}, 'Collect' : {'Id':'2', 'Name': 'tru'}},{"Active": {"Id":'1', 'Name': 'joe'}, 'Collect' : {'Id':'2', 'Name': 'mark'}}]
```

Here I am trying to use the filter where

```
tobefilter = "Peter"
```

Now, I am using the following way

```
const filterdata = _.filter(test => test.Active.Name === tobefilter)
```

this returns `empty array` . can any one help me out here..

Comment: You don't need lodash.  Just replace `_` with `test` and it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you are missing the first parameter - the array to be filtered

```
const filterdata = _.filter(test, test => test.Active.Name === tobefilter)
```

But you could do like this, provided that remember to construct the filtered source data first ([doc](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash))

```
const filterdata = _(test).filter(test => test.Active.Name === tobefilter)
```

```js
const test = [{"Active": {"Id":'1', 'Name': 'Peter'}, 'Collect' : {'Id':'2', 'Name': 'John'}},{"Active": {"Id":'1', 'Name': 'Peter'}, 'Collect' : {'Id':'2', 'Name': 'tru'}},{"Active": {"Id":'1', 'Name': 'joe'}, 'Collect' : {'Id':'2', 'Name': 'mark'}}]

const tobefilter = "Peter"

const filterdata = _(test).filter(test => test.Active.Name === tobefilter)

console.log(filterdata)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your first argument, which is the array to filter.  This is the correct way:

```js
const filterdata = _.filter(test, (x) => x.Active.Name === tobefilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

You are not passing array to be get filter.

```
const filterdata = _.filter(test,  (t)=> t.Active.Name === tobefilter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need lodash for this case? i mean its an single liner without it too.

```js
const test = [{"Active": {"Id":'1', 'Name': 'Peter'}, 'Collect' : {'Id':'2', 'Name': 'John'}},{"Active": {"Id":'1', 'Name': 'Peter'}, 'Collect' : {'Id':'2', 'Name': 'tru'}},{"Active": {"Id":'1', 'Name': 'joe'}, 'Collect' : {'Id':'2', 'Name': 'mark'}}]

const filterdata = test.filter(test => test.Active.Name === "Peter")

console.log(filterdata);
```